# Changing the opacity of individual slices of a Plotly pie-chart

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, pie-chart, plotly-python

I am building some interactive data-charts with plotly express & dash.
I already have some features like clicking on a piece to pull it from the pie-chart.

For improved highlighting, I wanted to adjust the opacity of the pulled piece.

The documentation states that you can pass a parameter for the keyword opacity between 0 and 1 in the function update_traces()..

`fig.update_traces(opacity=0.5)`

However, this affects the whole chart. I was wondering if it is possible to set the opacity for each slice individually (like with `fig.update_traces(pull=)` where you can pass a list for the pull of each slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since transparency only accepts float values, the CSS color name is specified in this reference [example](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#styled-pie-chart), but this can be handled by specifying transparency for each individual color with rgba(255,0,0,0.5), for example.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#colors = ['gold', 'mediumturquoise', 'darkorange', 'lightgreen']
colors = ['rgba(255,215,0,0.5)', 'rgba(72,209,204,0.75)', 'rgba(255,140,0,0.65)', 'rgba(144,238,144,0.9)']

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen'],
                             values=[4500,2500,1053,500])])
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='value', textfont_size=20,
                  marker=dict(colors=colors, line=dict(color='#000000', width=2)))
fig.show()
```

[image]

**example of reference**
[image]